# Parsing data in Bash

Tags: bash, parsing

I have a file with lots of Rubbish inside. All of it is in one line.
But there are often things like:

```
"var":"value"
```

Before and after are different characters ...

What I want to do is, to extract only the above mentioned format and put them into a single line. Any ideas how I could realize it in Shell scripting?

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: Can you give an example of a full line?

Answer (score 4):

I believe

```
grep -o '"[^"]*":"[^"]*"' yourFile.txt > yourOutput.txt
```

would do the trick:

```
> echo 'xxx "a":"b" yyy"x":"y"' | grep -o '"[^"]*":"[^"]*"'
"a":"b"
"x":"y"
```